# Avoiding snails around potted greenery?

Tags: pests, containers, harvesting, strawberries, snails

I had an idea about snail trap. I was wondering if placing a plastic ring in a form of a brush around a pot with needles pointing down would serve the purpose. Using very tiny spaced needles (i.e. low density per cm2) would force the hungry snail to fall down due to a small contact area, right? (See picture).[image]

Comment: No idea, but I would love to see the results of the experiment!

Comment: Shallow containers ( saucers) of beer is the typical snail trap. I never used it as I see no problem caused by snails.

Answer (score 1):

If you made it out of copper, it would work even better, but that will be more expensive.
Snails do not like to touch copper.

A chemical reaction happens when they crawl over the metal, which causes unpleasant feelings on their skin.

Al-tough not everyone will agree with me about this and I have seen snails just crawling over the copper, but most of them really hate it.